# Django and Docker Compose access media folder between containers

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a docker-compose app using Django and a container to check images validity, here's the project structure:

```
|-- backend
|   |-- backend
|   |   |-- asgi.py
|   |   |-- celery.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   `-- urls.py
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- media
|   |   `-- temp
|   |       `-- image.png

|   |-- profiles

|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile
|-- README.md
|-- requirements.txt

**|-- config/nginx/nginx.conf**
```

Here's the docker-compose configuration of django and nsfw:

```
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - database

  nsfw:
    image: eugencepoi/nsfw_api
    logging:
      driver: none
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      - PORT=5000

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Nginx configuration:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server app:8000;
}

server {

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

And here's when I try to access the source:

"{"error_code":404,"error_reason":"Not Found","url":"http://nginx/media/image.png"}\n"

Comment: Don't you want to use volume ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from the [EugenCepoi/nsfw_api](https://github.com/EugenCepoi/nsfw_api) repository, the service only supports http request. Also in production server, Django can't serve media contents, hence you can use [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to share contents between many containers. I recommend using a new NGINX service for serving the media files, so I am adding the nginx service to the docker-compose file:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/prod.env
    depends_on:
      - database

  nsfw:
    image: eugencepoi/nsfw_api
    logging:
      driver: none
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
volumes:
  media:
```

And create a nginx configuration file in in your `project directory/config/nginx/somename.conf`:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server app:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /app/path/to/static/; 
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

Now whatever content you add in `app` container's media folder, it will be available in `/app` directory of nginx container. Then nginx can serve these contents at nginx url.

```
url = "http://nginx:8000/media/temp/image.png"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and how will be the requests now?

Comment: I can't do it anymore, but the nsfw docker image support only http requests

Comment: I have just checked the repository. Hence I have updated my answer. Now Django will no longer serve the contents, rather the NGINX will

Comment: Thank you very much I'm going to implement it.

Comment: You can't run nginx on port 8000 since Django (the app container) already use it, I'm going to use 8001

Comment: you don't need to, Nginx will proxy django as well (added the configuration as well in the answer)

Comment: No I can't start docker compose if the port is 8000, so i set 80, now I post my code, KEEPING IN MIND my project structure.

Comment: I removed the ports 8000 from `app` service (please see the docker-compose I have shared)

Comment: I did not see you mention port number in the test url. also the image is inside temp directory, hence url should contain /temp/image.png. Also the configuration won't work because in nginx configuration you are listening 8000 port, whereas docker-compose is listening 8001

Comment: ok right, let me correct the code, but the paths are right configured in nginx?

Comment: I have updated the media path in nginx. it could be wrong but you can check inside the container to see if the volume path is correctly configured or not.

Comment: it works, really cool, thank you now I'm going to format the answer to maybe help someone else. Just one last thing, if I'm using NGINX installed on ubuntu as a server and now I use it in docker-container too, are there some conflicts? Thank yoy